# How to obtain the published ports from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, network-programming

I wrote a simple peer to peer system, in which, when starting  a node

- the node looks for a free port and then makes its service accessible on that port,
- it registers its URL including the port to a central server, so that other nodes know how to connect to it.

I have the impression this is a typical kind of task that docker is useful for, so I thought of making a container for these peers (my previous experience with docker has only been to write a hello world container).

Ideally I would map (publish) my exposed port to a host port from within the container using the same code that I am running now, but I could imagine that is simply not possible, and I could get around that by starting the image using a script that checks for availability of ports and then runs the container on an appropriate free host port. If the first is possible however, that would be even better. To be explicit, I do something like the following in Python

```
    port = 5001
    while not port_is_free(port):
        port += 1
```

The second part really has to be taken care of from within the container. Assume that it has been started with the command `docker run -p 5005:80 p2p-node` then I need to find out the published port 5005 that the exposed port 80 is mapped to *from within the container*.

Searching this site and the internet it looks like more people are interested in doing the same, but I couldn't find a solution, nor an affirmation that this simply cannot be done.

So this is the main question I want to ask: how can I see which published ports my exposed ports are mapped to from within a running docker container?

Comment: `I need access to the published port 5005 that the exposed port 80 is mapped to from within the container`, I wonder how would you access 5005 from container?  Accessing your local (container) 80 is hosts 5005, isn't it?

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul Sorry, I wasn't clear there, I didn't mean to access the port over the network, but just to obtain the published port, i.e. the value 5005. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your requirements are not clear to me.

However if you want to know only which host port is mapped with your container's port, you can simply pass an environment variable, [-e VAR=val](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables). Just an idea

Start container:

```
docker run -p 5005:80 -e HOST_PORT=5005 p2p-node
```

Access the variable from `container`

```
echo $HOST_PORT
```

there is [`docker-py`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py), a python library of docker.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you want the host port. In docker, containers can communicate with each other without having to expose ports on host machines.

As long as the peer apps are containerized, you don't need the expose port. The containers can be connected via a Docker network and the internal port can be used for communication between the containers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. In my case I want to allow nodes that run outside docker as well though.